# While try to add whitelist app using app name not works in G suite

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, gsuite-addons

When I'm trying to add using app name **app in google Admin=>Security=>App Access Control=>Apps**, it's not working

When I'm trying try to add using `clientid` **app in google Admin=>Security=>App Access Control=>Apps** working

I have attached a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Which kind of App are you talking about and how do you retrieve its client Id and name?

Comment: @ziganotschka i have created project in GCP and create credential also

Comment: It is certainly confusing, but the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en#) specifies: `To trust an app not on the list, at the top of the apps list, click Add app and select an option:

For web apps:

Click on OAuth App Name Or Client ID. 

Enter the client ID and click Search.

Select the app and click Add. `

So, you need to enter the `client ID`, not the `App Name`

Comment: I have already added app using client id @ziganotschka but i want to search using app name. I will send to my client id for users it's complicated thing , if it have any possibility to add app using app name

Comment: Well, according to the documentation it does not seem possible. I might want to contact GSuite support about this.